# Very strange section header view behavior for uitableviewcontroller (only last view appears)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with multiple sections headers each loading the same UIView. However, when I run the code in the simulator, only the last section header will appear. Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be the case.

Here is my SectionHeader method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(section < distinctPicklersHeaderArray.count)
    return [self picklerHeaderView];
return nil;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[image: UITableViewCell NOt Working]

**NOTE:** I am posting the picklerHeaderView method. However, I am not sure how to return a separate instance each time because I am merely going off of a tutorial.

```
-(UIView *)picklerHeaderView
{
// if we haven't loaded the headerView...
if(!picklerHeaderView){
    // load the headerview xib file
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PicklerDetailsDrillDownHeader" owner:self options:nil];
}
return picklerHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am having hard time understanding the functionality of the for loop here. What are you trying to do exacly? If the array count is equal to the number of sections, isn't this equal to simply  returning [self picklerHeaderView]; inside viewForHeaderInSection?

Comment: Maybe I went about this the wrong way, but I am trying to eventually customize the section view for each header so I need some way of knowing which section I am in.

Comment: I changed the method call to reflect Eiko's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can ease your job (not tested, probably contains typos):

Improve your method by adding the section index as parameter:

```
- (UIView *)picklerHeaderViewForSectionIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    //Create a view with a label maybe?
    UIView * v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 20)];
    UILabel * l = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 20)]; 
    //Mofify background colors and text color as you want here
    [l setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", section]];
    [v addSubview:l];
    [l release];
    return [v autorelease]
}
```

and and call it inside `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    return [self picklerHeaderViewForSectionIndex:section];

}
```

Dealing with UIView s may not be even necessary. Try overriding this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", section];
}
```

Comment: I still don't know how to return a separate instance of picklerHeaderView because the tutorial that I am following merely loads the nib. I'm assuming it does this because they only expect to have one section header.

Comment: Creating a custom view with a xib file is another problem you need to solve, you should look answered questions for that, or google. But loading specialized views the section parameter is the best choice. I am improving my answer to see how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working by returning a new instance of UIView each time.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I ditch trying to use the NIB?

Comment: For such a simple view, using IB is not necessary. But loading a custom view from NIB files is a necessary skill you need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Is that actual code you use? I ask because it doesn't really make sense.

It's equivalent to

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section < distinctPicklersHeaderArray.count)
        return [self picklerHeaderView];
    return nil;
}
```

Also, it seems you are getting the first header and not the last one.

So you will only get a header for "small enough" sections. If this is not what you want or get too few headers, check the contents of your array.

**Edit:**

Is `picklerHeaderView` returning new instances each time it is called, or is it returning a shared instance? You cannot share one view instance!

Comment: I think that you may have nailed it with your last comment about sharing an instance. I will look into that.

Comment: How would I return a separate instance based on the code at the bottom?

Comment: You shouldn't store that view in an instance variable and return that; instead, just alloc/init a new instance every time that method is called.

Comment: The other poster has suggested not using a nib at all. Do you think that this is a good idea/practice?

Comment: Yes, that will work. It doesn't matter if you do assemble your view in code or in a nib - just don't try to put the same instance twice on screen.